# Defining beans for different modules of project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My project includes three modules:

1. **koty-application** (data access objects)
2. **koty-domain** (value objects - model)
3. **koty-webapp** (web application using Spring MVC)

I am using Gradle to build project - **koty-application** produces *koty-application.jar*, **koty-domain** produces *koty-domain.jar* and **koty-webapp** produces *koty-webapp.war* (which includes jars).

Temporarily, I defined beans only for **koty-webapp** module. The structure is like this:
[image]

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Baza danych kotow</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.kobietydokodu" /> 
    <context:annotation-config /> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I defined beans for module **koty-webapp** and it works fine!
But I would like to define another beans for other module - for example *KotyDAO* for module **koty-application**. How should I define beans for **koty-application** module properly?

Full code of my project is here: https://github.com/evodv5/cats